# Two Buttons updating one item of a listview

Tags: asp.net, listview

I have two buttons in a ListView. With a click on the first Button I want to update the ListView-Item. With a click on the second button i want to update the ListView-Item and redirect to a different page. Both Buttons have a property `CommandName="Update"`. I wanted to solve my problem with the `CommandArgument`-Property and the `OnItemUpdated`-Event, but I do not know how to get the value of this Property in the event.

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ods" runat="server" SelectMethod="Select" UpdateMethod="Update">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:Parameter ..... />
    </SelectParameters>
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameters .... />
    </UpdateParameters>
</asp:ObjectDataSource>  

<asp:ListView ID="lv" runat="server" DataSourceID="ods" DataKeyNames="ID" OnItemUpdated="lv_OnItemUpdated">
    <ItemTemplate>...</ItemTemplate>  
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="btnUpdate" runat="server" CommandName="Update"/>
        <asp:Button ID="btnUpdate2" runat="server" CommandName="Update"/> 
    </EditItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

And in codebehind:

```
protected void lv_OnItemUpdated(object sender, ListViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    ...
}
```

Is it possible to decide in lv_OnItemUpdated which Button the user clicked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe there is a way to distinguish which control issued the Update command, since sender is the `ListView` itself.

A workaround would be for you to give one button the CommandName "**Update**", and the other "**UpdateRedirect**".
The "**UpdateRedirect**" button will fire the `ListView_ItemCommand` event, and from there you can call `ListView.UpdateItem`, keeping your updating logic in there, and then redirect next.

Why do you insist on using the `OnItemUpdated` event?

Answer (score 0):

Give each button a distinct name. Have the same event handling method in your code behind handle both button click events. Then check which button called the method.

**EDIT:** A workaround would be to use javascript to put the name of the clicked button into a hidden field on the form BEFORE it goes server side (using a client side script). Then in your Listview you could check the value of the hidden field to see which button was clicked.

Comment: I want the buttons to fire the update event of the ListView. When I handle the button click events the Update is not working.

Comment: So you want the page to display the changes in the ListView and THEN redirect?

Comment: Display changes is not necessary, but updating (writing update to database). Updating is not working when I handle the OnClick-Event.

Comment: Please give more information (in your opening post) what you mean by "updating is not working". Please show your code so we can try to help more.

Comment: Updating is working, but when I use ItemUpdating and ItemUpdated the OnClick Event of the Button will not be fired.

Answer (score 0):

Well there are 2 to 3 ways of doing it: One is of CommandArgument as:

```
<asp:Button id="Button1"
   Text="Sort Ascending"
   CommandName="Sort"
   CommandArgument="Ascending"
   OnCommand="CommandBtn_Click" 
   runat="server"/>
 <asp:Button id="Button2"
   Text="Sort Descending"
   CommandName="Sort"
   CommandArgument="Descending"
   OnCommand="CommandBtn_Click" 
   runat="server"/>
```

and than on server side you can have:

```
void CommandBtn_Click(Object sender, CommandEventArgs e) 
{
    if(e.CommandName == "Sort")
    //do you work and so on
}
```

or you can cast the sender as button and take it ID to see, which button was it:

```
((Button)sender)).ID
```

or you can get button ID as:

```
String ButtonID = Request["__EVENTTARGET"];
```

I hope it will help you in fixing your problem.

so you can have like:

```
protected void lv_OnItemUpdated(object sender, ListViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    // either use e.CommandName
    // or user ((Button)sender)).ID
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want to use OnItemUpdated-Event, if possible.

Comment: I have modified my answer, in end of it you can find your solution.

Comment: CommandName is "Update" and sender is the ListView and not a Button.

Comment: His problem is that CommandArgument is not a member of ListViewUpdatedEventArgs.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, yes, the itemcommand is what you want:
The lifecycle for an update or insert triggers both their native events AND the itemcommand event. The itemCommand event will occur prior to the itemUpdating or the itemInserting events.
So, you can create a boolean variable called called "bSecondButtonClicked" for example Add the command argument to both buttons with the Commandname='UPDATE". the e.command argument can be evaluated at the itemcommand event point. There set your Boolean variable (or however you implement it) to true. Then, at the itemupdating event, trigger your code based on the bSecondButtonClicked.

Answer (score -1):

You need to get into the `ItemCommand` event of your `ListView`

```
protected void lstvw_ItemCommand(object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.CommandName)
        {
            case "new":
                try
                {
                    //e.CommandArgument
                    //e.CommandSource
                    // do your stuff here
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                }
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want to use OnItemUpdated-Event, if possible.

Comment: you asked for solution and this does the job , now its matter of priority. I just tried to give a solution. if it works mark as answer.